# Update Attribute After Mailing Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I'm attempting to update an attribute called :lastemailed in my users model after sending an email, but having trouble getting it to work. I've tried putting it in my controller and mailer model but it hasn't worked. Here's the code I'm working with. Thanks for any help!

mailers/page_mailer.rb

```
class PageMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 add_template_helper(PagesHelper)

 default from: "mail@example.com"

 def reminder_send(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: "#{@user.email}", subject: "Your subject")
 end
end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def send_reminder_mail
 @user = User.find(params[:id])

 PageMailer.reminder_send(@user).deliver
 flash[:notice] = "Reminder sent!"
 redirect_to '/employees'
end
```

view that calls the mailer

```
<%= link_to "Email", :controller => "pages", :action => "send_reminder_mail", :id => u.id %>
```

The mailer works fine, I just can't get the attribute to update. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`:lastemailed` was a date datatype, and I was trying to save it using Time.now().

`Time.now()` is datetime datatype, so it needed to be formatted as `DateTime.now.to_date` in order to update properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your Pages Controller, after you send the email and before your redirect, add:

```
@user.update_attribute(:lastemailed, "New Value")
```